# Help with chat feature

Tags: usability, interaction-design, navigation, user-expectation, chat

I'm building the chat feature for a web project. We have a couple of specifications:

1. Support for general messages that will be broadcasted to all users subscribed to the room chat, and for that I have a tab called `General`.
2. Support for private messages where the current user must be able to select the receivers from the users list. So I've a `Users` tab with checkboxes elements, a textarea and a button at the bottom.

Here's a simple mockup that illustrates the scenario:

[image]

BTW I'm not a UX designer, so I'm looking for some suggestions.

- Should I activate the `Private` tab when the send button is clicked in order to show the conversations history?
- Or should I just override the users list and show there the conversations?

Comment: Ideally when dealing with a chat feature, you should be in the 'private chat' channel before starting you write the message. This should also allow you to view chat history or received messages.

Comment: Yep, `General` tab aim is hold the conversations broadcasted to all the chat-room users. And my dilemma is if should I use the `private` tab to list the individual conversations or just get ride that tab and use the same where the users list is?.

Comment: Spend some time in **Slack**. If you take their [break-out success](http://bit.ly/1PTcxzf) as evidence, users (and investors) are quite pleased with their chat solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would divide it in public and private. BTW I'm not aware of mobile conventions (maybe top buttons should be inside a hamburger menu to save space or to have 1 control with all the possible actions in that page).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fif9ui.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**An alternative** would be to make the "Choose participants dialog" a tab (similar to your users tabs) and removing the cancel button. For me it would depend on how much actions you can do respect to users (apart from start a conversation).

Anyway it's always good to show who are participating in the chat when you are in a private conversation, showing the icon as the other answer states is a good option. (I didn't include it in the mockups)

Comment: Wow, definitely it is a great explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You could use chat bubbles in a horizontal list (which is technically a tab) like on the facebook messenger app, with a small number within a circle to indicate the amount of unread messages

Here's a chat plugin i found quite user friendly. Even being quite feature heavy, it seems easy to use. might give you some ideas

[image]

www.spot.im